# PHP Access Denied Error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a login script, PHP based. when I run the page I get the following error:
Access denied for user 'usernameI'@'mydomainname.com' (using password: YES)

I've confirmed my password and that the respective user has all rights to the database. I tested a small connection script and get the same error. Here is the code:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("mydomainname.com","usernameI","mypassword");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

...I have the above within the body tag of the PHP page. Could I get some help as to what I'm doing wrong or if there is something I've overlooked or need to confirm? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have mysql server installed on the same machine that you are running script?

Comment: Yes, everything is setup on a server hosted by GoDaddy.com

Comment: `mysqli_connect("mydomainname.com"` should probably be `mysqli_connect("localhost"` ... unless you're literally trying to connect to the database on your domain from a different machine.

Comment: @user1724708 do you try loggin with "localhost"?

Comment: Thanks, that resolved it!